# How to deal with multiple enumeration types in one variable

Tags: c#

I don't know if this is possible or not, but I'm writing a simple game using XNA and C#, and somehow need one particular variable to be able to handle more than one enumeration type. The character you control has a single inventory slot, which can be one of the fruit types below:

```
public enum Fruit : int {Apple, Banana, Orange};
public Fruit carrying;
```

But the character can also be able to carry something else:

```
public enum Misc : int {Parcel, Brush};
```

I don't want to merge them all into one enum because I want the Fruit enumeration to be distinct, and I don't want to have to have two different 'carrying' variables - one for Fruit and one for Misc.

Is there any way of having, say, a super-enumeration, that can merge them together into a third enumeration of all five members?

EDIT: thanks for the responses. I have decided to create a single Item type (a member of which is an enumeration that differentiates between Fruit and Misc) and load them into a List via XML.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you probably want a union type for `CarriableItem` or something similar. For example:

```
public sealed class CarriableItem
{
    public Fruit? Fruit { get; private set; }
    public Misc? Misc { get; private set; }

    // Only instantiated through factory methods
    private CarriableItem() {}

    public static CarriableItem FromFruit(Fruit fruit)
    {
        return new CarriableItem { Fruit = fruit };
    }

    public static CarriableItem FromMisc(Misc misc)
    {
        return new CarriableItem { Misc = misc };
    }
}
```

You might *also* then want another enum to indicate which kind of item is being carried:

```
public enum CarriableItemType
{
    Fruit,
    Misc
}
```

Then add a property to `CarriableItem`:

```
public CarriableItemType { get; private set; }
```

and set it in the factory methods appropriately.

Then your person would have just a single variable of type `CarriableItem`.

Answer (score 0):

Why limiting yourself to an enum? If you have an interface and various implementations of it you can customize the behavior of your items!

```
// generic item. It has a description and can be traded
public interface IItem {
    string Description { get; }
    float Cost { get; }
}

// potions, fruits etc., they have effects such as
// +10 health, -5 fatigue and so on
public interface IConsumableItem: IItem {
    void ApplyEffect(Character p);
}

// tools like hammers, sticks, swords ect., they can
// be used on anything the player clicks on
public interface IToolItem: IItem {
    void Use(Entity e);
}
```

This will make your code easier and more structured than using enums to discriminate between different items. And if you still need to do that, you can take advantage of the `is` operator and the method `IEnumerable.OfType`. So here's what you can do:

```
public class HealthPotion: IConsumableItem {
    public string Description {
        get { return "An apple you picked from a tree. It makes you feel better."; }
    }

    public float Cost {
        get { return 5f; }
    }

    public void ApplyEffect(Character p) {
        p.Health += 1;
    }
}

public class Player: Character {
    public List<IItem> Inventory { get; private set; }

    private IEnumerable<IConsumableItem> _consumables {
        get { return this.Inventory.OfType<IConsumableItem>(); }
    }

    public void InventoryItemSelected(IItem i) {
        if(IItem is IConsumableItem) {
            (IItem as IConsumableItem).ApplyEffect(this);
        }
        else if(IItem is IToolItem) {
            // ask the player to click on something
        }
        else if /* ...... */

        this.Inventory.Remove(i);
    }
}
```